# How to create a model through text field with validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, railscasts

I followed the tutorial ["Create a model through text field" (Railscast #57)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/57-create-model-through-text-field) which works so far. Though, I noticed that neither the *select field* nor the *input field for the new object* get validated.

I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `validates` for the affected models. Everything worked fine before I added the form fields. Now, when I submit the form without *selecting* or *entering* anything no warning occurs. This produces faulty database entries of course.

**Edit 1:** I added screen shots of the forms and the *internship model*.

- [New internship form with all fields and validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t66i.png)
- [New internship form with select and input fields from the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuFte.png)

One example: While creating a *new internship* I want to be able to select a *company* **or** *create a new one*. I added the code as described in the tutorial but I am unsure what to do about the validation.
Here is the *internship model*.

```
class Internship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :study
  belongs_to :company

  attr_accessor :new_company_name, :new_company_website
  before_save :create_company_from_data

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :study

  validates :from, :presence => true
  validates :till, :presence => true
  validates_associated :company, :study

  def create_company_from_data
    create_company(:name => new_company_name, :website => new_company_website, :kind => false) unless new_company_name.blank?
  end

end
```

I am using Rails 3.0.5.

Comment: Show some code, please. It is hard to use mind reading powers over the internet.

Comment: Thank you: it saves me/us from having to look at the screencast. Which rails version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works for me.

Here is the internship model.

```
class Internship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :new_company_name, :new_company_website

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :study
  belongs_to :company, :class_name => "Facility", :foreign_key => 'facility_id'
  has_one :student, :through => :study

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :study

  validates :from, :presence => true
  validates :till, :presence => true
  validates_presence_of :study
  validates_presence_of :company, :unless => :new_company_given?
  validates_presence_of :new_company_name, :new_company_website, :unless => :company_given?

  before_save :create_company_from_data, :if => :new_company_given?

private

  # Returns a boolean value indicating whether a company is available.
  # @return [Boolean] True if a company is available; otherwise false.
  def company_given?
    return self.facility_id.present?
  end

  # Returns a boolean value indicating whether a new_company is available.
  # @return [Boolean] True if a new_company is available; otherwise false.
  def new_company_given?
    return (self.new_company_name.present? or self.new_company_website.present?)
  end

  # Creates a new company object taking into account the given parameters.
  def create_company_from_data
    create_company(:name => new_company_name, :website => new_company_website, :kind => false)
  end

end
```

Here is the form partial of the new-internship-form.

```
<%= error_messages_for @internship %>

<div class="formbox">

  <div class="formseparator">When?</div>

  <%= render :partial => "shared/internship_form_fields", :locals =>  { :internship_fields => internship_fields } %>

  <div class="formseparator">Where?</div>

  <p>
    <span class="formlabel"><%= internship_fields.label :facility_id, "Company" %></span>
    <span class="formvalue"><%= internship_fields.select :facility_id, Facility.companies.sorted.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, { :include_blank => "Please select a company." }, { :class => "single" } %></span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span class="formlabel"><%= internship_fields.label :new_company_name, "or create a new", :class => "optional" %></span>
    <span class="formvalue"><%= internship_fields.text_field :new_company_name, :class => "input" %></span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span class="formlabel"><%= internship_fields.label :new_company_website, "with a website", :class => "optional" %></span>
    <span class="formvalue"><%= internship_fields.url_field :new_company_website, :class => "input" %></span>
  </p>

  <!-- End of company_fields -->

  <div class="formseparator">Your study?</div>

  <p>
    <span class="formlabel"><%= internship_fields.label :study_id, "Study" %></span>
    <% mystudies = Array.new %>

    <% studies = Study.sorted.collect %>

    <% studies.each do |study| %>
      <% if (study.student == current_user) %>
        <% mystudies.push(study) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <span class="formvalue">
      <%= internship_fields.select :study_id, mystudies.collect { |s| [s.study_text, s.id] }, { :include_blank => "Please select one of your studies." }, { :class => "single" } %></span>
  </p>

  <!-- End of study_fields -->
</div>
<div class="form-buttons"><%= internship_fields.submit "Submit" %></div>
```

Though, I do not like that the new_company fields sit in the internship model instead in the facility model where they belong.